# Having trouble uploading a file with node using multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

This seems like a simple problem, but I've been spending a while trying to solve it and I can't quite figure out what's wrong.  This is my frontend form that is making the request:

```
div#PreGA
    p PreGa.json:
    form(action="config/set/PreGa", name="pre-ga", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
        input(type="file" value="Choose File" accept=".json")#choose-file-pre-ga
        input(type="submit" value="Upload")#upload-pre-ga
```

This is the route that should receive the request:

```
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

//set the JSON file for the pre-ga reported issues
router.post('/config/set/PreGa',ensureAuthenticated, upload.single('pre-ga'), function(req, res, next) {


    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.file);

});
```

The issue is that req.file, which should return the file, is undefined when the route is called.

This is one of the simplest use cases, and I can't figure out what's going wrong.  It would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file input is missing a `name` attribute.

Comment: Oh, I thought that I needed the name for the form input... Thanks.  Also, it should be req.file and not req.files because I'm using single() and not array() according to the multer documentation.  It does work now, though.  I can't believe I didn't see that!